# Value of the integral in the interval.

Tags: definite-integrals, conic-sections

The length of perpendicular from foci $S,S'$,on any tangent to ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$$ are $a,c$ respectively then value of $\int \{x\}dx$ from $-ac$ to $ac$ is ?(where {} denotes the fractional part.).

**My attempt**. Now this is a standing ellipse so I assumed a tangent at $(4,0)$ as we know the distance between tangent and  focus is $4$. And by symmetry we can say $a=c$ so $-ac=16,ac=16$ now I am not getting what is that $n$ and how to compute the integral. Thanks

Comment: Use \{ and \} to display { and } in latex

Comment: In fact, what is $Nx$ ?

Comment: @G Cab can you help me now

Comment: What is a standing ellipse?

Comment: A vertical ellipse as $a<b$